# python Pandas can't import completely data csv dute to whitespace

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, whitespace

I'm beginner
I can't import completely CSV data to pandas. Date in CSV have whitespace inserted in the character in 2 column ['Test Results','S/N'] make it not import complete data.

How to solve this?

my code

```
scores_df = pd.read_csv('20210112.csv')
print(scores_df)
```

Data after import.

```
Date      Time  Millisecond  Pumping time  Heating time  temperature  time  water weight  Power  Voltage  Testing time Test Results  S/N
0    2021/01/13  00:00:41          540           175           589         1899   291          2290   1427      118          1179            O    2
1    2021/01/13  00:03:11          350           175           569         1899   317          2280   1461      118          1181            O    2
```

Data in CSV file

```
"Date","Time","Millisecond","Pumping time","Heating time","temperature","time","water weight","Power","Voltage","Testing time","Test Results","S/N"
"2021/01/13","00:00:41","540","175","589","1899","291","2290","1427","118","1179","O K ","2 1 B . A 1 5 4 . 0 1 6 2 1 6 9 "
"2021/01/13","00:03:11","350","175","569","1899","317","2280","1461","118","1181","O K ","2 1 B . A 1 5 4 . 0 1 6 2 1 7 7 "
```

[image: my CSV data]

[image: Data when import to pandas]

Comment: can you post the text (not an image) of a sample of the csv data?

Comment: Data in CSV file
me","Millisecond","Pumping time","Heating time","temperature","time","water weight","Power","Voltage","Testing time","Test Results","S/N"
"2021/01/13","00:00:41","540","175","589","1899","291","2290","1427","118","1179","O K ","2 1 B . A 1 5 4 . 0 1 6 2 1 6 9 "
"2021/01/13","00:03:11","350","175","569","1899","317","2280","1461","118","1181","O K ","2 1 B . A 1 5 4 . 0 1 6 2 1 7 7 "

Comment: import to pandas
Date      Time  Millisecond  Pumping time  Heating time  temperature  time  water weight  Power  Voltage  Testing time Test Results  S/N
0    2021/01/13  00:00:41          540           175           589         1899   291          2290   1427      118          1179            O    2
1    2021/01/13  00:03:11          350           175           569         1899   317          2280   1461      118          1181            O    2

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue from the provided information. I think the posted answers hint at correct things to try - the only other thing I can imagine is invisible characters.  Open the csv in an editor that will display invisible chars to see if there is something strange going on there

Comment: I still struck this issue, I tried to convert my CSV file to txt. then convert back to CSV I've found pandas can import completed value.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably fine just adding the `sep=','` arg to `read_csv`, since it seems the autodetection may not be working in your case. However, to cover all bases you should also add the `quotechar='"'` argument to ensure that any separators within quoted strings will be ignored.:

```
scores_df = pd.read_csv('20210112.csv', sep=',', quotechar='"')
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it still got same result.

,Date,Time,Millisecond,Pumping time,Heating time,temperature,time,water weight,Power,Voltage,Testing time,Test Results,S/N
0,2021/01/13,00:00:41,540,175,589,1899,291,2290,1427,118,1179,O,2
1,2021/01/13,00:03:11,350,175,569,1899,317,2280,1461,118,1181,O,2
2,2021/01/13,00:06:23,420,173,591,1899,286,2300,1419,117,1176,O,2

Answer (score 0):

```
scores_df = pd.read_csv('20210112.csv', sep=',')
```